# how to get or place face grids on specified tick marks in Ticks using ListPlot3D

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, ticks, grid-lines

```
 mat11 = {{1.875`, 1.8919`, 1.9543`, 2.1989`}, 
         {1.7227`, 1.7352`, 1.7792`, 1.8996`}, 
         {1.42`, 1.4253`, 1.4427`, 1.4778`},
         {1.2479`, 1.2508`, 1.26`, 1.2769`}}


    min = Round[Min@{mat11}, .01];
    max = Round[Max@{mat11}, .01];
    minmax = {min, max}

    Table[
 Legended[
  ListPlot3D[MATRIX, 
   ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"DarkRainbow", minmax}],
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
   Mesh -> Automatic,
   MeshStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[0], Dotted],
   PlotLabel -> Framed[Style[Row[{"Spring const. ratios: ",
        Subscript[\[Kappa], 1], " = 1, 1000 and ", 
        Subscript[\[Kappa], 2], " = 1"}], FontFamily -> "Times", 25, 
      Black, Background -> None]],
  InterpolationOrder -> 3,
  PlotRange -> {{1, 4}, {1, 4}, {0.75, 2.25}},
  ImageSize -> 500,
  AxesLabel -> {Style[\[Mu], 30, FontFamily -> "Times", Bold, Red], 
              Style[\[Eta], 30, FontFamily -> "Times", Bold, Blue]},
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.9],

  ViewPoint -> {-3, -2.9, 2},
  FaceGrids -> {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, -1}},
  FaceGridsStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, Dashed],

  Ticks -> {{{1, "0"}, {2, "0.2"}, {3, "0.4"}, {4, "0.6"}}, {{1, 
   "0"}, {2, "0.1"}, {3, "0.5"}, {4, "1"}}, {0.75, 1, 1.25, 1.5, 
  1.75, 2, 2.25}}, 
  TicksStyle -> 
  Directive[Black, FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 18]],
  Placed[BarLegend[{"DarkRainbow", minmax}, 9, LegendMarkerSize -> 500,
  LegendLayout -> "Row", 
  LabelStyle -> 
    Directive[Black, Bold, FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 18]], 
 Below]],
{MATRIX, {{mat11} }}][![plot for code above][1]][1]
```

> I want to find out a way of inserting face grids at specified intervals in ListPlot3d.  These interval are specified in Ticks.  The intervals show in the figure below are whole numbers only.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

Let

```
ticks = {{{1, "0"}, {2, "0.2"}, {3, "0.4"}, {4, "0.6"}}, 
         {{1, "0"}, {2, "0.1"}, {3, "0.5"}, {4, "1"}}, 
         {0.75, 1, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2, 2.25}};
xticks = ticks[[1, All, 1]];
yticks = ticks[[2, All, 1]];
zticks = ticks[[3]];
```

and change the specification of `FaceGrids` to

```
FaceGrids -> {{{1, 0, 0}, {yticks, zticks}}, {{0, 1, 0}, {xticks, zticks}}, {0, 0, -1}}
```

Using the relevant part of your code:

```
Legended[ListPlot3D[mat11, 
  ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"DarkRainbow", minmax}], 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Mesh -> Automatic, 
  MeshStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[0], Dotted], 
  PlotLabel -> Framed[Style[Row[{"Spring const. ratios: ", Subscript[κ, 1], 
       " = 1, 1000 and ", Subscript[κ, 2], " = 1"}], 
     FontFamily -> "Times", 25, Black, Background -> None]], 
  InterpolationOrder -> 3, 
  PlotRange -> {{1, 4}, {1, 4}, {0.75, 2.25}}, ImageSize -> 500, 
  AxesLabel -> {Style[μ, 30, FontFamily -> "Times", Bold, Red], 
    Style[η, 30, FontFamily -> "Times", Bold, Blue]}, 
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.9], ViewPoint -> {-3, -2.9, 2}, 
  FaceGrids -> {{{1, 0, 0}, {{0}, zticks}}, {{0, 1, 0}, {{0}, zticks}}, {0, 0, -1}}, 
  FaceGridsStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, Dashed], Ticks -> ticks, 
  TicksStyle -> Directive[Black, FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 18]], 
 Placed[BarLegend[{"DarkRainbow", minmax}, 9, LegendMarkerSize -> 500,
    LegendLayout -> "Row", 
   LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 18]], Below]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]